# Determining "filters" dimension after a convolution operation

Tags: cnn, dimensionality-reduction, matrix

I tried to calculate the "filtered" dimension and I seem to be getting it wrong.

Below there is the image I am trying to calculate the "filtered" dimension for, where you have 192 of depth, and the operations applied are 3x3x192 conv, and 2x2-s-2 MaxPool(is strides).

My idea was that you would get 1 because you would operate the convolution in all the depth at once.

How do you get 256 from the 192 and operations?

#### [SOURCE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf)

[image]

Comment: If you share the source of the diagram, maybe we can understand better what they are doing.

Comment: Yes, it is the YOLO original paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf @noe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the complete figure 3, you can get the clues to understand the missing pieces:

[image]

There, you can see that the figure only shows some of the intermediate results from the total of 24 convolutional layers.

In the figure, in each of the intermediate results shown, the outer tensor represents the output tensor while the inner one represents the convolution filter tensor.

The depth "192" that we can see in the figure detail you posted is actually the depth of the tensor obtained after applying the convolutional layer 3x3x192 and the max pooling layer 2x2 with stride 2.

The "256" on the right side of the figure detail is the result of applying the 3x3x256 convolution that appears in the third text column of the complete figure.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I can not upvote just because I have score 1, and need 15+ to upvote.

Comment: I just realize that by following this method I can not get to the third dimension of the third box, How am I supposed to do it? The second box of  size 112x112x192, though Conv 3x3x192 and then MaxPool 2x2 does not yield 256 dimension in depth, which is the question I am asking

Comment: Oh, I was doing wrong. Thank you again